# Remove all extra text before and after domain string per line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would like to take the following strings in and only keep the domains and `<br>` tags

So:

```
390796,domain1.com,1,0,0,false<br> 
390796,43domain2.org,2,0,0,false<br> 
167854,domain3.com,0,1,0,false <br>
167854,5domain4.com,0,1,0,false<br>
```

Would end up like:

```
domain1.com<br>
43domain2.org<br>
domain3.com<br>
5domain4.com<br>
```

I would prefer that I do this in [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things: 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried

Answer (score 2):

Search & Replace with Regular Expressions checked.

**Search:** `^\d+,([^,]+),.*`

**Replace:** `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Although the Regex is probably the best way to do it(see Radoo's answer), it is also fairly difficult to master.

You can also record macros in Notepad++.
[image: Macro]
Place your cursor at the beginning line and click on the Record button (red circle).
Then fix the line using keyboard only(use <kbd>End</kbd> Key to get the end of line).
Finally move the cursor with your keyboard to the next line (<kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>) and press stop.

You can then use the Run Macro Multiple times button to run it on each line.

This is far easier then RegEx conceptually but will only work if the data structure is identical.